# JavaFX undecorated window performance issues

Tags: java, windows, javafx, jna

To customize a window's title bar, I made it an unadorned window, but then suffered high performance losses.

The mouse events I use while dragging and resizing the window are not fast enough for this job.

Is it possible to resize and drag an undecorated window without using javafx mouse events?

Main.java

```
package main;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

public class Main extends Application { // JavaFX Office Application Main Class

    double xLength, yLenght;
    boolean maximized = false, resizebottom; // variables
    double xOffset, yOffset, xCor, yCor, dx, dy;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("main.fxml"));
        AnchorPane root = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1366, 900);


        // Move Operations

        HBox titleBar = (HBox) loader.getNamespace().get(
                "titleBar");


        titleBar.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
            xOffset = primaryStage.getX() - event.getScreenX();
            yOffset = primaryStage.getY() - event.getScreenY();
        });

        titleBar.setOnMouseDragged(event -> {

            if (maximized) {

                primaryStage.setX(event.getScreenX());
                primaryStage.setWidth(xLength);
                primaryStage.setHeight(yLenght);
                maximized = false;
            } else {

                primaryStage.setX(event.getScreenX() + xOffset);
                primaryStage.setY(event.getScreenY() + yOffset);
            }
        });

        // Button Operations

        Label maximizeButton = (Label) loader.getNamespace().get(
                "maximizeButton"
        );

        maximizeButton.setOnMouseClicked(mouseClickEvent -> {

            if (!maximized) {

                xLength = primaryStage.getWidth();
                xCor = primaryStage.getX();
                yLenght = primaryStage.getHeight();
                yCor = primaryStage.getY();
                root.setStyle("-fx-border-insets: 0;\n" +
                        "    -fx-background-insets: 0;");
                primaryStage.setX(0);
                primaryStage.setY(0);
                primaryStage.setWidth(1920);
                primaryStage.setHeight(1050);
                maximized = true;
            } else {

                primaryStage.setWidth(xLength);
                primaryStage.setX(xCor);
                primaryStage.setHeight(yLenght);
                primaryStage.setY(yCor);
                root.setStyle("-fx-border-insets: 5;\n" +
                        "    -fx-background-insets: 5;");
                maximized = false;
            }
        });


        Label closeButton = (Label) loader.getNamespace().get(
                "closeButton"
        );

        closeButton.setOnMouseClicked(mouseClickEvent -> {

            primaryStage.hide();
        });


        Label minimizeButton = (Label) loader.getNamespace().get(
                "minimizeButton"
        );

        minimizeButton.setOnMouseClicked(mouseClickEvent -> {

            primaryStage.setIconified(true);
        });


        scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        ResizeHelper.addResizeListener(primaryStage);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

ResizeHelper.java

```
package main;

import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.event.EventType;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

//created by Alexander Berg
public class ResizeHelper {

    public static void addResizeListener(Stage stage) {
        ResizeListener resizeListener = new ResizeListener(stage);
        stage.getScene().addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED, resizeListener);
        stage.getScene().addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, resizeListener);
        stage.getScene().addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, resizeListener);
        stage.getScene().addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED, resizeListener);
        stage.getScene().addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED_TARGET, resizeListener);
        ObservableList<Node> children = stage.getScene().getRoot().getChildrenUnmodifiable();
        for (Node child : children) {
            addListenerDeeply(child, resizeListener);
        }
    }

    public static void addListenerDeeply(Node node, EventHandler<MouseEvent> listener) {
        node.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED, listener);
        node.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, listener);
        node.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, listener);
        node.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED, listener);
        node.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED_TARGET, listener);
        if (node instanceof Parent) {
            Parent parent = (Parent) node;
            ObservableList<Node> children = parent.getChildrenUnmodifiable();
            for (Node child : children) {
                addListenerDeeply(child, listener);
            }
        }
    }

    static class ResizeListener implements EventHandler<MouseEvent> {
        private Stage stage;
        private Cursor cursorEvent = Cursor.DEFAULT;
        private int border = 4;
        private double startX = 0;
        private double startY = 0;

        public ResizeListener(Stage stage) {
            this.stage = stage;
        }

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
            EventType<? extends MouseEvent> mouseEventType = mouseEvent.getEventType();
            Scene scene = stage.getScene();

            double mouseEventX = mouseEvent.getSceneX(),
                    mouseEventY = mouseEvent.getSceneY(),
                    sceneWidth = scene.getWidth(),
                    sceneHeight = scene.getHeight();

            if (MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED.equals(mouseEventType) == true) {
                if (mouseEventX < border && mouseEventY < border) {
                    cursorEvent = Cursor.NW_RESIZE;
                } else if (mouseEventX < border && mouseEventY > sceneHeight - border) {
                    cursorEvent = Cursor.SW_RESIZE;
                } else if (mouseEventX > sceneWidth - border && mouseEventY < border) {
                    cursorEvent = Cursor.NE_RESIZE;
                } else if (mouseEventX > sceneWidth - border && mouseEventY > sceneHeight - border) {
                    cursorEvent = Cursor.SE_RESIZE;
                } else if (mouseEventX < border) {
                    cursorEvent = Cursor.W_RESIZE;
                } else if (mouseEventX > sceneWidth - border) {
                    cursorEvent = Cursor.E_RESIZE;
                } else if (mouseEventY < border) {
                    cursorEvent = Cursor.N_RESIZE;
                } else if (mouseEventY > sceneHeight - border) {
                    cursorEvent = Cursor.S_RESIZE;
                } else {
                    cursorEvent = Cursor.DEFAULT;
                }
                scene.setCursor(cursorEvent);
            } else if(MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED.equals(mouseEventType) || MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED_TARGET.equals(mouseEventType)){
                scene.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
            } else if (MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED.equals(mouseEventType) == true) {
                startX = stage.getWidth() - mouseEventX;
                startY = stage.getHeight() - mouseEventY;
            } else if (MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED.equals(mouseEventType) == true) {
                if (Cursor.DEFAULT.equals(cursorEvent) == false) {
                    if (Cursor.W_RESIZE.equals(cursorEvent) == false && Cursor.E_RESIZE.equals(cursorEvent) == false) {
                        double minHeight = stage.getMinHeight() > (border*2) ? stage.getMinHeight() : (border*2);
                        if (Cursor.NW_RESIZE.equals(cursorEvent) == true || Cursor.N_RESIZE.equals(cursorEvent) == true || Cursor.NE_RESIZE.equals(cursorEvent) == true) {
                            if (stage.getHeight() > minHeight || mouseEventY < 0) {
                                stage.setHeight(stage.getY() - mouseEvent.getScreenY() + stage.getHeight());
                                stage.setY(mouseEvent.getScreenY());
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (stage.getHeight() > minHeight || mouseEventY + startY - stage.getHeight() > 0) {
                                stage.setHeight(mouseEventY + startY);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (Cursor.N_RESIZE.equals(cursorEvent) == false && Cursor.S_RESIZE.equals(cursorEvent) == false) {
                        double minWidth = stage.getMinWidth() > (border*2) ? stage.getMinWidth() : (border*2);
                        if (Cursor.NW_RESIZE.equals(cursorEvent) == true || Cursor.W_RESIZE.equals(cursorEvent) == true || Cursor.SW_RESIZE.equals(cursorEvent) == true) {
                            if (stage.getWidth() > minWidth || mouseEventX < 0) {
                                stage.setWidth(stage.getX() - mouseEvent.getScreenX() + stage.getWidth());
                                stage.setX(mouseEvent.getScreenX());
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (stage.getWidth() > minWidth || mouseEventX + startX - stage.getWidth() > 0) {
                                stage.setWidth(mouseEventX + startX);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```